# Where can I register for WNS in Windows Developer Center

Tags: uwp, wns, windows-dev-center

I want to know how to enable Windows Notification Services for UWP apps.

Answer (score 0):

The steps to enable WNS for your UWP app have changed, but the documentation has not yet been updated.

To enable WNS:

1. Register for a [developer account](https://developer.microsoft.com) at developer.microsoft.com
2. Create a new app - you can do this through Visual Studio by right clicking your UWP app > Store > Associate app with store
3. In Microsoft Developer Center, select **your app** and go to **App Management** > **WNS/MPNS**. Follow the link to Live Services Site
4. Here you can find your **app secret** and **Package SID** required to enable WNS